# finding max number of consecutive 1 in a string?

Tags: r

Is there any easy way to get maximum number of consecutive 1's in a string like: 
`"000010011100011111001111111100"` ?

I, definitely, can do it with loops but I'd like to avoid that since my actual dataset has about 500,000 records.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried (and other questions from the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist))?

Comment: I only tried using loops. I have two loops one as a counter on row number that starts from the first row of the dataset and goes all the way to the end. Another loop as a counter of number of consecutive 1's. But it's very inefficient and takes a long time to run.

Comment: @Thomas, you are right. I searched but I didn't find anything. I should've used better keywords to search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rle`:

```
x <- "000010011100011111001111111100"
rr <- rle(strsplit(x,"")[[1]])

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:9] 4 1 2 3 3 5 2 8 2
  values : chr [1:9] "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0"
```

**Note:** I removed the `as.numeric` part as it's not necessary. From here, you can get the maximum count of consecutive 1's with:

```
max(rr$lengths[which(rr$values == "1")])
# [1] 8
```

Comment: @Arun - I think that should be a separate answer rather than an edit. If you do so, I can probably delete mine then.

Comment: @thelatemail, Yes, I realise that now. posted separately. Thanks. (Thomas, sorry for the mess).

Comment: How can I do this if I want to create a separate column? I tried doing it for a column and i am getting the same value for all rows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Using `rle` is slower and a bit more clumsy than using regular expressions.  In [Thomas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18004508/271616), you're still left to extract the max length when the values equal 1.

```
# make some data
set.seed(21)
N <- 1e5
s <- sample(c("0","1"), N*30, TRUE)
s <- split(s, rep(1:N, each=30))
s <- sapply(s, paste, collapse="")
# Thomas' (complete) answer
r <- function(S) {
  sapply(S, function(x) {
    rl <- rle(as.numeric(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]))
    max(rl$lengths[rl$values==1])
  })
}
# using regular expressions
g <- function(S) sapply(gregexpr("1*",S),
   function(x) max(attr(x,'match.length')))
# timing
system.time(R <- r(s))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.41    0.00    6.41
system.time(G <- g(s))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    1.47    0.00    1.46
all.equal(R,G)
# [1] "names for target but not for current"
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative **much faster** way *without using `rle`* would be to split with consecutive 0's as follows:

```
# following thelatemail's comment, changed '0+' to '[^1]+'
strsplit(x, "[^1]+", perl=TRUE)
```

Then you can loop over and get maximum characters for each element of your list. This'll be faster than `rle` solution as well. and is also faster than the `gregexpr` solution from @Joshua. Some benchmarking...

```
zz <- function(x) {
    vapply(strsplit(x, "[^1]+", perl=TRUE), function(x) max(nchar(x)), 0L)
}
```

I just realised that @Joshua's function could also be tweaked by adding `perl=TRUE` and using `vapply`. So, I'll compare that as well.

```
g2 <- function(S) vapply(gregexpr("1*",S, perl=TRUE),
   function(x) max(attr(x,'match.length')), 0L)

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(t1 <- zz(unname(s)), t2 <- g(unname(s)), t3 <- g2(unname(s)), times=50)
Unit: seconds
                expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 t1 <- zz(unname(s)) 1.187197 1.285065 1.344371 1.497564 1.565481    50
  t2 <- g(unname(s)) 2.154038 2.307953 2.357789 2.417259 2.596787    50
 t3 <- g2(unname(s)) 1.562661 1.854143 1.914597 1.954795 2.203543    50

identical(t1, t2) # [1] TRUE
identical(t1, t3) # [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice. To generalise in the case where there are characters other than `0` or `1` would be to replace `"0+"` with `"[^1]"` in the `strsplit` call. *Marginally* slower, but probably safer.

Comment: Yes indeed, you're right. But I don't think it'll affect the performance.

Comment: about 50% slower in my testing. From 0.5s to 0.75s.

Comment: Just did the benchmark again. It takes 1.1 seconds with "0+" and 1.22 with "[^1]+".

Comment: How to get the max of value in the list using loop? Please advise, thanks so much @Arun